# Looking for IPs by page visited in apache log (awk?)

Tags: apache-2.4, shell, log-files, ip-address

I have a bunch of apache access log files and I want to know which IP addresses visited my /contacts folder. How can I collect them from all log files with shell command?

Comment: you may find this helpful: http://serverfault.com/questions/11028/do-you-have-any-useful-awk-and-grep-scripts-for-parsing-apache-logs/

Comment: show example of your log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use simple grep and awk command to filter records and show IPs. For common log format you can use something like this:

`cat /path/to/apache/accesslog/dir/* |grep "/contacts" |awk '{ print $1 }' |sort -u`

Or there is better way - setup some central logging and analyzing tool (like ELK stack) and use it for global analyzing across time and data.

Comment: UUOC and UUOG ;) `awk '/contacts/ {print $1} /path/to/apache/accesslogdir/*`

Comment: maybe too complicated but I cannot remember higher syntax of awk that this to "print field number x in stdin and print it out" so this works for me.